# Memory corruption when using SIGALRM and timer

Tags: linux, memory, gcc, signals, corruption

Ok not really sure if it is memory corruption or just a bug in my code, but here is the description of the problem:
Single threaded program registers a SIGALRM handler:

```
struct sigaction action;
sigset_t blocked;

sigfillset(&blocked);
sigdelset(&blocked, SIGKILL);
sigdelset(&blocked, SIGSTOP);

action.sa_handler = &handler_function;
action.sa_flags   = SA_RESTART;
action.sa_mask    = blocked;

// We are not interested in the previous action:
if (sigaction(SIGALRM, &action, NULL) == -1)
   ....
```

handler_function is a simple function which calls a function of an object:

```
void handler_function()
{
     some_object->tick();
}

tick()
{
    ++variable;
}
```

Variable is of type long.
my program has only one instance of some_object and only signal handler calls function tick and only tick function modifies variable. Other functions only read value of variable.
Forgot to mention that I create a timer:

```
struct timeval interval;
interval.tv_sec   = 0;
interval.tv_usec  = (100000);

struct itimerval timer;
timer.it_interval = interval;
timer.it_value    = interval;
if (setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &timer, NULL) == -1)
...
```

so tick function is triggered 10 times per second. Now the problem is that intermittently i get other data members of object some_object corrupted, they are POD types(long), i.e. all of a sudden they contain random values. I've tried to isolate a problem in a small program, but to no avail.
Any advise would be appreciated.
thanks

Comment: Disable the signal handler and see if the corruption still occurs - perhaps it is nothing to do with the signals.

Comment: Indeed it was nothing todo with timer. It was a buffer overflow in socket reading code. The reason why all the time the same variables where corrupted was that this object was always created after buffer allocation, so whenever buffer was overflown it would overflow to that object...

Answer (score 0):

There's a buffer overflow in your socket reading code. Fix that and the problem will go away.